# RewriteRule to fetch last two parameters of url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok so I have this .htaccess file and it fetches the first dir after base as $1 and the second as $2

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond $1 ^[^\.]+[^/]$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?sub=$1&page=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?sub=$1&page=$1 [L]

    #RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?sub=$1&page=$2 [L]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$      index.php?sub=$1&page=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now we need to test this website on the productionserver in a subdirectory. This would add an additional directory to url

so: 
hxxp://localhost/newwebsite/var1/var2/

Is there a way to only fetch the last two parameters of an url or should I just thrust it is going to work the way we want it. (not really an option)

Thanks!

Comment: So the `.htaccess` file given is what you already have and you want to know how to add another rule to capture something in the directory `newwebsite`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the htaccess file in the `newwebsite` directory and change the `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /newwebsite/`.